# Selenium Python how to run an XPath error handling exception on loop with multiple def?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

is it possible to schedule my code by running it with schedule.every(10).seconds.do(example) or similar? I'm trying to schedule the Error Handling part in my code (XPath) which works with a While loop although because its in a While loop it refuses to run the other def functions, I want the XPath/error handling part to run in a loop with my Selenium window but detect and not interfere with the other def functions. it should just detect the XPath being there or not being there then run an exception if it doesn't detect.. Does anyone have a solution?

My code:

```
def example():
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                              options=options)

    driver.get("example.com")
    driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
    driver.set_window_size(750, 512)

    while True:
        e = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/button/span")
        if not e:
            print("Element not found")
            pyautogui.moveTo(89, 56)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click()

        time.sleep(10)


def example2():
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

    driver.get("example.com")
    driver.set_window_position(750, 0)
    driver.set_window_size(750, 512)

    while True:
        e = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/button/span")
        if not e:
            print("Element not found")
            pyautogui.moveTo(850, 57)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click()

schedule.every().day.at("22:59").do(example)
schedule.every().day.at("22:59").do(example2)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach tries to use a blocking `while True` loop inside your `example` and `example2` functions, which continuously checks for the presence of an element by its XPath. This will indeed block any other code execution including scheduled tasks, as Python's default execution model is single-threaded. If one part of the code is in an infinite loop or a long-running operation, it effectively freezes everything else.

My suggestion is that you should use Python's `threading` library to run your blocking loops in separate threads. This allows your main program to continue running and executing other scheduled tasks without being blocked by the infinite loops in `example` and `example2`.

```py
import threading
import schedule
import time
# Import other necessary modules like Selenium, pyautogui, etc.

def example():
    # Your existing code for example function

def example2():
    # Your existing code for example2 function

# Schedule tasks as before
schedule.every().day.at("22:59").do(example)
schedule.every().day.at("22:59").do(example2)

# Run the example functions in their threads
example_thread = threading.Thread(target=example)
example2_thread = threading.Thread(target=example2)

example_thread.start()
example2_thread.start()

# Run the scheduler in the main thread
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

There is another approach that you can use.Instead of using a `while True` loop within your `example` and `example2` functions, consider restructuring your code to check for the element at scheduled intervals. This can be done directly with the `schedule` library by scheduling the check itself, instead of putting it in an infinite loop.

For instance, you could create a function dedicated to checking the element's presence and then schedule this function to run every 10 seconds or so, alongside your other tasks. This avoids the need for a blocking loop and allows the scheduler to manage when the checks occur.

For handling exceptions such as an element not being found (which seems to be your primary concern), make sure to wrap the relevant part of your code in a try-except block. This will catch exceptions related to the element not being present and allow your code to react accordingly (e.g., clicking somewhere else on the page).

Please be cautious about accessing shared resources from multiple threads simultaneously, as this can lead to race conditions. Use threading locks if necessary to avoid such issues.

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Dowjones, works perfectly with threading.